# How to return a value from a method back to the input value

Tags: python, python-2.7, methods, return-value

I have created a helper method to check the zip code format for a country. Because I have multiple zip codes (e.g. visit, postal) I would like to like to use this helper method. 
When I debug I can see that self.zip is put into the value zipcode, but when it runs trough the method zipcode updates as it should, but it does not return the value back to self.zip.

Could someone explain to me how I could get this to work?

```
def onchange_zip(self):
    self.postal_code_format(self.zip, self.country_id)

def postal_code_format(self, zipcode, country):
    if country.name == "Netherlands":
        zipcode = zipcode.replace(" ", "").upper()
        if len(zipcode) == 6:
            numbers = zipcode[:4]
            letters = zipcode[-2:]
            if letters.isalpha() and numbers.isdigit():
                zipcode = str("{0} {1}").format(numbers, letters)
            else:
                raise ValueError("Could not properly format the postal code.")
        else:
            raise ValueError("Could not properly format the postal code.")
        return zipcode
```

Comment: So is this in a class? What are the inputs? Could you give a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say

```
zipcode = zipcode.replace(" ", "").upper()
```

you are making `zipcode` to refer to a new string object. It no longer refers to the `self.zip` object.

The right way to do this would be is assigning the value back to `self.zip` like this

```
self.zip = self.postal_code_format(self.zip, self.country_id)
```

Or reassign the value in `postal_code_format` function itself, instead of returning, like this

```
self.zip = zipcode
```

---

**Note:** String objects are immutable anyway. It means that, any operations on the string objects will give you a new string object, they will not modify the original object. For example,

```
>>> string_obj = 'thefourtheye'
>>> string_obj.upper()
'THEFOURTHEYE'
>>> string_obj
'thefourtheye'
```

As you see here, `string_obj.upper()` returns a new string object with all upper case letters, but the original object remains unchanged. So you cannot change the value at `self.zip`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply thefourtheye. So if I get this right this would mean I have to copy this code for every seperate zip code if I want it to be formatted the right way?

Comment: @JohanVergeer That is one way to solve the problem. Otherwise, you can update the `self.zip` with the new string object in `postal_code_format` function itself, as I have shown in the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd recommend that in your onchange_zip function, you change the line:

```
self.postal_code_format(self.zip, self.country_id)
```

to

```
self.zip = self.postal_code_format(self.zip, self.country_id)
```

If you take this approach, the postal_code_format function simply returns a formatted postal code - it doesn't have any side effects (like updating self.zip everytime it is called, that's a side-effect) - and whatever calls it does what it wants with the formatted code, in this case the onchange_zip updates the self.zip value. Now if postal_code_format is called by other code that wants a formatted postal code, it won't affect self.zip.

Answer (score 0):

At the line of `postal_code_format(self, zipcode, country):` put

```
self.zip = zipcode
```

Note: no need to explicitly pass zipcode and country as variable to function

```
def postal_code_format(self):
    country = self.country_id
    zipcode = self.zip
```